# How can I get data from two different database tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am creating an endpoint (GET /feed) where
user can view all articles or gifs, showing the most recently posted articles
or gifs first. It is to return the following as JSON

- id​: Integer​
- createdOn: DateTime
- title: String
- article/url: String (use url for gif post and article for articles)
- userId: ​Integer​

Here is my article and gif table,

```
CREATE TABLE article(
    article_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(300),
    article text ,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT Now() 
);

CREATE TABLE gif(
    gif_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL ,
    cloudinary_id VARCHAR (3000),
    url VARCHAR(3000) ,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT Now()
)
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821738/how-can-i-get-data-from-two-tables)?